# how do i check the difference between the current price and a certain price?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

i created a strategy but i'm struggling to implement something.
i went through the documentation but i can't seem to find a solution or anything regarding obtaining the current price.

so let us say the strategy bought nas100 at 13000.00 and the current price of nas100 is 13075.00 which is a 75 pips gain/profit. so i want to calculate the difference between the price the strategy bought at and the current price. if the difference between the price the strategy bought at and the current price is >= 50 pips i want the strategy to create a stop loss order and put it 5 pips above the price at which the strategy bought and then trail the price every +5 pips it moves. how can i implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`close` will refer to the current price.

You can use `strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades-1)` to get the last entry price.

Then do your calculations.